# Can I reject the input captured from the oninput binding?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to reject input from the `oninput` [binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/oninput)?

i.e.

```
var inputEl = document.getElementById("myinput");

inputEl.addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (this.value < 0) {
    return false; // Reject input; replace with previous value
  } else {
    // Valid input.
  }
});
```

Comment: if u put this on fiddle or snippet it would be better

Comment: Just set `this.value=""`

Comment: What do you mean by reject input? Do you mean to replace the new value inside the text input with the previous value?

Comment: @LiXinyang yea, kind of like you might do in a keydown event.

Comment: Check out my solution below, does it meet your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Codepen solution can be found at,

https://codepen.io/li-xinyang/pen/MpgYMW?editors=0011

```js
var el = document.getElementById('input');
var previousVal = "1234";

console.log(el);

el.addEventListener('input', function() {
  console.log(this.value);
  if (parseInt(this.value) < 0)
    this.value = previousVal;
  else {
    previousVal = this.value;
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input">
```